# Openlayers : graphic opacity for both externalGraphic and backgroundGraphic

Tags: openlayers, opacity

Speaking about : [OpenLayers.Feature.Vector](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Feature/Vector-js.html), when I want to separatly set the opacity of backgroundGraphic and externalGraphic properties, there is only one parameter for both : graphicOpacity.

Did someone found a trick to solve this problem ?

Comment: As I understand it, the opacity only applies to externalGraphic which will always be on top of backgroundGraphic. Can't you preset the opacity of backgroundGraphic to whatever you want and adjust the externalGraphic opacity on top?

Comment: I think graphicOpacity applies to backgroundGraphic too because both graphics' opacity change when I set graphicOpacity value.